# Spring Boot error With Jersey applicationContext.xml not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey

I'm creating my first project with Spring boot and Jersey and These are my project files, 
The First one is Application.java class

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The Second one is HelloResource.java

```
package hello;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

and The third one is JerseyConfig.java

```
package hello;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@Component
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(HelloResource.class);
    }
}
```

After running the app using "mvn spring-boot:run: command, i tried to access this URL "http://localhost:8080/hello", it shows me this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: Spring Boot won't look for that file by default so something else must be doing it. A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve) would be useful here

Comment: As Andy said, you must have something else that's requiring this file (maybe something in `src/main/resources`?. 
Check this simple [Jersey project with Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey), no XML is needed.